# Setting the correct specific Time Zone in the Philippines

Tags: java, android, android-studio

so I have a DateFormat function in my android app which calculate and show the date and time of the "data" that has been posted on my database. Surely enough, It shows on my app, but not the correct time. "GMT" isn't the right one, and "GMT+8" doesn't work, i also tried "Asia/Manila" but with no avail. Any help is appreciated.

```
  private String calculateTimeAgo(String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Manila"));
    try{
        long time = sdf.parse(date).getTime();
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        CharSequence ago =
                DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(time, now, DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
        return ago+"";
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Basically, you are better off not using `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`.  The javadoc is unclear, but when you call `DateFormat.parse`, the timezone that you set previously is overridden.  It doesn't determine the zone used to parse the date.  Use the Java 8+ date/time APIs: https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro

Answer (score 0):

you can use Instant data type. It stores the date and time in UTC format, and then converts it into LocalDateTime with timeZone.

for example:

```
    Instant instantDateTime = Instant.now(); // 2022-07-28T05:46:07.652147008Z
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instantDateTime, ZoneOffset.UTC); //2022-07-28T05:46:07.652147008
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instantDateTime, ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate(); //2022-07-28
```

Now you get your local date and time. I think this can help you, Thank you.